# Android Maven compilation error (Multiple Dex File)

Tags: android, maven, android-appcompat

I'm tryin to add AppCompat library (v7) to Maven. I downloaded it by SDK-Deployer, everything goes fine, no compilation errors, but I tried to do **mvn clean install** on my project and I saw this:

*Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.6.0:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project reader-android: MojoExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = cmd.exe /X /C "C:\SDK\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\aapt.exe package -m -J "C:\Users\Przemek\Desktop\Book Reader\pd_proj\reader-android\target\generated-sources\r" -M "C:\Users\Przemek\Desktop\Book Reader\pd_proj\reader-android\AndroidManifest.xml" -S "C:\Users\Przemek\Desktop\Book Reader\pd_proj\reader-android\res" --auto-add-overlay -A "C:\Users\Przemek\Desktop\Book Reader\pd_proj\reader-android\assets" -I C:\SDK\sdk\platforms\android-20\android.jar", Result = 1 -> [Help 1]*

I'm a little confused, don't know what to do.

I've just added this to my project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
    <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
    <version>19.0.1</version>
    <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

I've heard that it can cause errors:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <sdk>
            <platform>20</platform>
        </sdk>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**

Probably it's my main problem:

**Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.AppCompat').**

Answer (score -1):

Try to compile with sdkversion 20 or greater.

If you use gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    targetSdkVersion 20
}
```

Comment: I'm using Maven, set targetSdk to 20 and platform to 20, but thanks.